# I am trying to crate a quiz program that uses a text files and count score. But score is not working

Tags: python

i am creating a python quiz program that uses two text files i.e one for questions and one for answers.

```
1|What is the colour of mango ?|a.Yellow b.Blue c.Black d.Brown
2|What is the colour of apple ?|a.Yellow b.Red c.Black d.Brown
3|What is the colour of chochlate ?|a.Yellow b.Blue c.Black d.Brown
4|What is the colour of water ?|a.Yellow b.Blue c.Black d.Brown
```

Questions.txt

```
1|a
2|b
3|d
4|b
```

Answers.txt

The program should also count the score i.e if correct +1 and if wrong the do nothing. But the score counter is not giving correct results.
Here is the code

```
QuestionsText = open("Questions.txt",'r')
AnswersText = open("Answers.txt",'r')
Questions = QuestionsText.readlines()
Answers = AnswersText.readlines()
Score = 0
i=0
while i<4 :
  for Question in Questions:
    for Answer in Answers:
      AnswerPart = Answer.split('|')
      AnswerNumber = AnswerPart[0]
      RightAnswer = AnswerPart[1]
    QuestionPart = Question.split('|')
    QuestionNumber = QuestionPart[0]    
    ActualQueston = QuestionPart[1]
    Options = QuestionPart[2]
    print (QuestionNumber,'.',ActualQueston)
    print (' ',Options)    
    UserAnswer = input("Your Answer is = ")
    print('SUBMITTED')
    if UserAnswer == RightAnswer :      
      Score = Score + 1
      i=i+1
    else :
      i = i + 1
             
print("Your Score is =",Score)
```

This time I tried to run some tests that where the actual problem is going. I printed the right answer at every iterations just to find if its taking the values correctly.

```
QuestionsText = open("Questions.txt",'r')
AnswersText = open("Answers.txt",'r')
Questions = QuestionsText.readlines()
Answers = AnswersText.readlines()
Score = 0
i = 0
while i < 4:
  for Question in Questions:
    for Answer in Answers:
      AnswerPart = Answer.split('|')
      AnswerNumber = AnswerPart[0]
      RightAnswer = AnswerPart[1]
      print("Test 0",AnswerNumber,RightAnswer)
      QuestionPart = Question.split('|')
      QuestionNumber = QuestionPart[0]    
      ActualQueston = QuestionPart[1]
      Options = QuestionPart[2]
      print("Test 1",AnswerNumber,RightAnswer)
      print (QuestionNumber,ActualQueston,Options)
      UserAnswer = input( " Your Answer is : " )
      print(UserAnswer)
      print(RightAnswer)
      if UserAnswer == RightAnswer :
        print("Test 2",AnswerNumber,RightAnswer)
        print('Right')
        Score = Score + 1
        print("R",Score)
        i = i + 1
      else :
        print("Test 3",AnswerNumber,RightAnswer)
        print('Wrong')
        print("W",Score)
        i = i + 1
        break      
print("Your Score is =",Score)
```

so at the end upto the if statement every values are taken correctly but after it though both the useranswer and right answer is the same still it says wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is not working? Any errors? You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should move the check for right answer into a function, as it is now e.g. your RightAnswer is the last answer in the file.

Comment: The [[tag:python-requests]] tag usage guidance clearly states: *"USE ONLY FOR THE PYTHON REQUESTS LIBRARY. Requests is a full-featured Python HTTP library with an easy-to-use, logical API"*. I don't see you're using this library

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop for the answers is the problem. The code as it is, iterates about all answers, so the RightAnswer is always the same. For your supplied Answers, it's `b`.
So you detect wrong answers and so get a wrong score.

**EDIT**:
An implementation, which should work, is for example:

```py
# Assumption 1: every line in Questions.txt is one set of question and possible answers
# Assumption 2: every line in Answers.txt is one set of question number and correct answer
# Assumption 3: the order of questions in Answers.txt and Questions.txt is the same
QuestionsText = open("Answers.txt",'r')
AnswersText = open("Questions.txt",'r')
Score = 0
i = 0
# iterate over both files simultaneously
# q and a are one line in the regarding file
for q,a in zip(QuestionsText,AnswersText):
    # split q in number, question and options
    question_number,question,options = q[:-1].split("|")
    # split a in number and correct answer
    solution_number,solution = a.split("|")

    # start the test by printing in console
    # print the question
    print(f"Question {question_number}:\n{question}")
    #print the options
    print(options)
    useranswer = input("What is your answer? Please type in the letter of the option and press enter\n")
    # upper makes it case insensitive
    if solution.upper().startswith(useranswer.upper()):
        Score += 1
        print("Your answer is correct.")
    else:
        print(f"Your answer is wrong. The correct answer ist {solution}.")
    i += 1
print(f"You answered {Score} of {i} questions correct.")
```

This gives you:

```
Question 1:
What is the colour of mango ?
a.Yellow b.Blue c.Black d.Brown
What is your answer? Please type in the letter of the option and press entera
Your answer is correct.
Question 2:
What is the colour of apple ?
a.Yellow b.Red c.Black d.Brown
What is your answer? Please type in the letter of the option and press enterb
Your answer is correct.
Question 3:
What is the colour of chochlate ?
a.Yellow b.Blue c.Black d.Brown
What is your answer? Please type in the letter of the option and press enterd
Your answer is correct.
Question 4:
What is the colour of water ?
a.Yellow b.Blue c.Black d.Brow
What is your answer? Please type in the letter of the option and press entera
Your answer is wrong. The correct answer ist b.
You answered 3 of 4 questions correct.
```

Comment: So can you suggest any changes that I can make. I am new to this so i dont have much knowledge.